# Spring Boot Jackson taking large amount of memory

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot is taking around 3 gb memory to convert 300 mb payload to object

The `POST` request payload which i am sending to Spring boot web application is 300 mb. But the SpringBoot application esp Jackson parser is talking around 3gb of memory to map request to its corresponding object.

Due to this issue, i am directly reading the stream and i have written custom parser to parse the payload and map it to the object.

The payload in the form of JSON is follows:

```
{"a": "some value", "b": "this value is around 300 mb string"}
```

Why is Springboot Jackson parser taking 3 gb memory to map the JSON payload to object? I have not written any custom code, i believe SpringBoot internally uses Jackson to map JSON to Object.

Is SpringBoot or Jackson parser suited to parse 300 mb payloads?
**Note: Only one of the element in my JSON payload is around 300 mb.**

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the JSON is most ASCII characters, then your payload is all 1-byte characters. Java strings are UTF-16 encoded, so each character is 2 bytes.

This means that your 300 mb payload is a 600 Mb `char[]` in memory.

Since the payload is mostly a JSON string literal, that literal needs to be extracted, i.e. copied. Since the size is unknown, it is likely copied into a `StringBuilder`. That `StringBuilder` will have a 600 Mb `char[]`, and then a string is created from it, which is another 600 Mb `char[]`.

So, simply extracting the string value of the `b` field will consume 3 times 600 Mb. i.e. 1.8 Gb of memory, and you haven't even begun to allocate memory for your objects yet.

Sure, the `StringBuilder` is eligible for GC before you start that, but you've still consumed 1.2 Gb of memory before you start creating your POJOs.

Comment: Good  Explanation  @Andreas

Comment: Thank you. We came to the same conclusion after looking at the heap dump. My custom implementation is something like this, as we know the content length of the payload, so i don't need `StringBuilder`, i can copy the 600 mb character array to String. So here i am using only 1200 mb. My question is why is Jackson parser taking more memory?  Do you suggest any other alternate way to handle this huge payload?

Comment: @bigdata How can you not need `StringBuilder`? You don't know that length of the full string, unless you're *guaranteed* to only use ASCII characters. You don't know the length of the `b` string, because you don't know how many characters are escaped.

Comment: @Andreas does annotating b as clob data type make jpa stream instead of loading the string in the memory.?